# React Bootstrap Typeahead specifies the length of characters in the input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeahead.js, react-bootstrap-typeahead

First problem: Why, if I enter one letter in input, `console.log (this.state.results.length)` does not show me `1`. Only after entering two letters `console.log (this.state.results.length)` shows me `2`.

Second problem: I will type three letters, then remove two letters, `console.log (this.state.results.length)` should show me `1` and show`2`. The same is when I clear the input it should show `0`;

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-frleaq

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      results: ''
    };
  }

_handleSearch = query => {
  this.setState({
    results: query
  })
}


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.results.length)
    return (
      <div>
         <AsyncTypeahead
            clearButton
            id="basic-example"
            labelKey="name"
            onSearch={this._handleSearch}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Demo and the code in the question are different.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I corrected

Comment: Besides of that, what do you actually want? Do you want to make AsyncTypeahead work?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I want to check the length of characters entered in the input AsyncTypeahead

Comment: But why? Does it matter? What will you do that with it?

Comment: @SuleymanSah The field is empty button is hide. Enter the letter - button show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203812/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-umbro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onInputChange`  to handle text changes  and you can keep the text in state. This way you can check it's length and do whatever you want.

Example:

```
import React from "react";

import { AsyncTypeahead } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      multiple: true,
      options: [],
      selectedUsers: [],
      currentInput: ""
    };
  }

  handleSearch = query => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch(
      `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${query}+in:login&page=1&per_page=3`
    )
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(({ items }) => {
        const options = items.map(i => ({
          id: i.id,
          name: i.login
        }));
        return { options };
      })
      .then(({ options }) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          options
        });
      });
  };

  handleChange = selectedItems => {
    this.setState({
      selectedUsers: selectedItems,
      currentInput: ""
    });
  };

  handleInputChange = input => {
    this.setState({
      currentInput: input
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedUsers, isLoading, options, currentInput } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <AsyncTypeahead
          clearButton
          id="basic-example"
          isLoading={isLoading}
          options={options}
          minLength={3}
          multiple
          labelKey="name"
          onSearch={query => this.handleSearch(query)}
          onChange={selectedItems => this.handleChange(selectedItems)}
          onInputChange={input => this.handleInputChange(input)}
          placeholder="Search for users"
        />
        <hr />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        {currentInput.length > 0 && <button>MY BUTTON</button>}
        <hr />
        Selected {selectedUsers.length} Users: <br />
        <ul>
          {selectedUsers.map(user => (
            <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```